# Kommasetzung bei Verb + Infinitiv

Tags: punctuation

Neben den Modalverben gibt es einige, an die ein Infinitiv ohne "zu" angeschlossen werden kann/muss.

> Ich höre dich singen.
>
> Ich gehe einkaufen.

Nun kann man beide Prädikate natürlich auch ausbauen. So weit, dass sie sich nicht mehr als Einheit anfühlen

> Ich gehe mit meiner Lampe auf den Dachboden(,) das alte Hochzeitsvideo von Tante Lena suchen.

Mal abgesehen davon, dass das etwas umgangssprachlich ist...

- Wie wird die Kommasetzung bei diesen Sätzen gehandhabt? Komma, kein Komma?
- Wenn Komma, dann wo ist die Grenze?

... es ist ja nicht:

> Ich gehe, schlafen.

Comment: Mir erscheint der Satz übrigens falsch. Ich halte ein „zu“ für nötig, sobald das „auf den Dachboden“ eingefügt wird.

Answer (score 4):

Es handelt sich hierbei um einen sogenannten **[Akkusativ mit Infinitiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusativus_cum_infinitivo#Deutsch)** (Accusativus cum infinitivo, AcI).

Der einzige Grund, warum hier eine Abtrennung durch ein Komma in Frage kommen könnte, wären [Infinitivgruppen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitivgruppe), die immer durch ein Komma abgetrennt werden können (§ 75 E2) und manchmal müssen (§ 75). Leider definieren die offiziellen Regeln nicht, was genau sie unter einer *Infinitivgruppe* verstehen, aber aus den Beispielen und dem, was ich so im Netz gefunden habe, würde ich schließen, dass ein *zu* enthalten sein muss und demnach AcI-Konstruktionen nicht hierunter fallen.

Daher und nach meinem allgemeinem Sprachempfinden würde ich in so einem Fall **nie** ein Komma setzen – es sei denn, die AcI-Konstruktion soll als Einschub verstanden werden, z. B.:

> Ich gehe mit meiner Lampe auf den Dachboden, das alte Hochzeitsvideo von Tante Lena suchen.

Hier würde durch das Komma die Betonung auf die erste Hälfte des Satzes (vor dem Komma) gelegt werden und die zweite Hälfte als Zusatz gekennzeichnet. Beim Sprechen würde ich zwischen den beiden Satzhälften eine deutliche Pause machen.

Comment: Totally agree. Kein Komma, es sei denn, es ist ein Nachtrag.

Answer (score 3):

Die Konstrukte bei denen ein Komma immer wenigstens optional, teils sogar notwendig ist, sind all jene mit "um zu" + Infinitiv.
Dein Beispiel

> Ich gehe mit meiner Lampe auf den Dachboden(,) das alte Hochzeitsvideo von Tante Lena suchen.

ist ausformulierbar als

> Ich gehe mit meiner Lampe auf den Dachboden, um das alte Hochzeitsvideo von Tante Lena zu suchen.

Man sieht, dass hier eine Absicht ausgedrückt wird. (Man spricht von einem "Finalsatz".) Hingegen ist

> Ich gehe, um zu schlafen.

reichlich sinnlos.

Also als Faustregel: Wenn der Satz mit "um ... zu" ausformulierbar ist -> Komma setzen.

Comment: Wenn du "um zu" verwendest, ist ein Komma **immer** obligatorisch. Der erste Satz räumt aber ein, es gebe Ausnahmen dazu. Ist aber nicht so.

Comment: Anyway. Ich denke, die Frage von Emanuel zieht auf jene Sätze ab, in denen man nicht "um zu" verwendet.

Comment: Schöne Antwort, danke. Ich habe noch ein paar weitere Beispiele durchgespielt und bin zu dem Schluss gekommen, dass eine "um zu"-erweiterung immer dann möglich ist, wenn das erste Prädikat erweitert ist. "Ich gehe die Lampe holen." vs "Ich gehe in die Küche, (um) die Lampe (zu) holen. ürdest du da zustimmen?

Comment: Wieso sollte eine Konstruktion ein Komma erfordern, nur weil eine bedeutungsähnliche Konstruktion existiert, die ein Komma erfordert? Mit dem gleichen Argument müsste man »ein, laut schnarchender, Hund« mit eben diesen Kommata schreiben, weil in »ein Hund, der laut schnarcht« ein Komma gesetzt werden muss.

Comment: Wrzl: Wie der Fragesteller schon anmerkte, ist das weglassen der Konjunktion wohl eher umgangssprachlich. Em1: Du hast recht.